# Output of \qed symbol in LaTeX within a proof environment at the end of an enumerate statement

Tags: latex, enumerate, amsmath

My aim is to place the `\qed` symbol in the same line in which the last `\item` statement within a `\begin{enumerate}` block with enumitem is placed.
In the proofs I've developed I got three different results:

1. Using **amsmath**, the `\qed` symol is placed in a next line.
2. Using `\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}`, the result is the same (`\qed` in the next line).
3. With `\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}`, it appears the text "None" in the place in which the `\qed` symbol must appear (that is, in the same line in which ends the statement `\item`)

I've found a strange and not easy solution writing `\vspace{-1.5\baselineskip}` after any one of the `\end{enumerate}` statements or adding `\hspace{1cm} \qedhere` into the last line of a math formula.
What I'm doing wrong?

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Conjunto de símbolos matemáticos
\usepackage{amsthm}  % Formato para enunciados y demostraciones
\usepackage{enumitem}
%
\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
%\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
%
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
%
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Result is:

[image: Result of the code]

Comment: please make a compilable [mre], so we don't have to dig through all your text to find the code bits

Comment: (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks might also be interesting)

Comment: See next example:

Answer (score 1):

Never ignore error messages. Your code does not compile. The error message in the log file will tell you that the plain theorem style is already defined when you try to load the `ntheorem` package after you've already loaded `amsthm`. After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output. There is no point in looking at the result as long as you've errors. As you can see from your example, the output just does not make sense.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb} % Conjunto de símbolos matemáticos
%\usepackage{amsthm}  % Formato para enunciados y demostraciones
\usepackage{enumitem}
%
\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
%\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
%
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
%
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\begin{proof}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to replace the \qedsymbol by \blacksquare? (there is a \renewcommand statement but no effect).

Comment: @LuisSubirana If you have a new question, please ask a new question!